# Not able to read deleted replies with rep >10k?

Tags: support

I have recently magically increased my reputation to be 32k, but I still can't read those deleted replies and comments, for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91953/what-inferential-method-produces-the-empirical-cdf). Can I? 
p.s. Happy everyday!

Comment: You're a long way from 32K.  Please visit http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges to review which privileges are associated with which levels of reputation. Question deletion does not become possible until 10K, so I would guess you cannot read deleted material until you have reached that level.  Consider contributing some good answers to our site; they can help grow reputation faster.

Comment: I am already 32800, following the link in my post and also here http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1005/tim.

Comment: Sorry; you are misreading the numbers.

Comment: @whuber, I think this is an SE April fools day gag. They are offering "magic unicoins" that you can use to do things like increase your reputation, etc. I suspect it will last 1 day only, and not have any real effects (ie, no extra privileges).

Comment: Thanks @gung. I feel deceived, because the unicoins have no effect on how *I* read the reputation values. Such a stark difference in how the site is presented to two people creates potential for misunderstandings, conflicts, and worse. I like a joke as much as anyone but this one doesn't look funny to me.  Tim, I am sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: @whuber: Sorry that you feel deceived.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is an SE April fools day gag.  They are offering "magic unicoins" that you can use to do things like (appear to) increase your reputation, etc.  I am not surprised that it does not have any real effects (for example, you don't get the extra privileges that would come with that reputation).  I predict that it will be gone at midnight GMT.

Comment: it is just my little fantasy.